# ace editor - remove text dragging and selection

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is possible to remove the text drag & drop and text selection features in the ace editor?

I'm looking for a solution to this, but I can't find a solution to disable these features..

I've tried to disable the mouse listeners, and editor functions, but with no success:

```
function DragdropHandler(){};
window.DragdropHandler = 'null';
```

and

```
editor.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown.bind(mouseHandler));
```

This does not work, and I don't think this is the right way..

I hope there is a simple way to disable the features..

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts, putting things like "Please Help..." or "thanks" in question isn't good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable dragging use

```
editor.setOption("dragEnabled", false)
```

To disable all mouse events add a listener that stops them

```
function stop(e) { e.stop() }
["mousedown", "dblclick", "tripleclick", 
 "quadclick", "click", "mousemove"].forEach(function(name) {
    editor.on(name, stop)
})
```

your example of removing mosuedown can't work because bind returns a new function every time so you are trying to remove a listener that never was registered in the first place!

you can do `editor.removeAllListeners("mousedown")` instead.

Comment: How do you know all these things about the ace editor? In the github or ace website api, I can't find these...

Comment: How did you search? list of options can be found here https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Configuring-Ace, Stopping events and removeAllListeners is the way many event systems work. 
Also inspecting objects in js console is usually much faster than using documentation.

Comment: Yes, but I'm new to this.. and sometimes it's hard for me :)

Comment: Just keep trying and you'll be master very soon :)

Comment: Thank you bro :) Just another thing: any idea to prevent the selection using CTRL+A (selectall) and selection using SHIFT+arrows ??

Comment: You can remove the commands. But what are you trying to do? There must be a better way to do that.

Comment: To solve this I'm trying to re-assign custom commands (empty) to these shortcuts, do you think that this is the proper way?

Comment: Could you explain why are you trying to do all this. What end result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, I also need to disable text selection. My final target is to prevent copy.  of text. I tried all the commands mentioned in your answer but only   function stop(e) { e.stop() }
["mousedown", "dblclick", "tripleclick", 
 "quadclick", "click", "mousemove"].forEach(function(name) {
    editor.on(name, stop)
})        worked for me.    
On occurrence of some other event, I want to re-enable text selection and copy. I have very less experience with java script. could you tell me how can i enable the things i disabled. Also I am curious why editor.setOption("dragEnabled", false) didn't work

Comment: do the same with `editor.off(name, stop)` to remove stop function

Comment: Thanx It worked for me. But I am cursious why is nothing else didn't work. did setOption and removeAllListeners also worked for u?

Comment: setOption is to disable dragging not selection, and removeAllListeners is just a way to remove unknown listener function